# Can not see "Windows Forms App (.NET)" Template in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, winforms

**Some Details**

I do not use WinForms as much but I needed it for some work. I have got new computer some months ago > I installed Visual Studio > I have not worked with WinForms till then.

**Problem**

I can not find "Windows Forms App (.NET)" Template in Visual Studio ( Images at End ). But I can see "Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)" Template.

**Images**

***Visual Studio Workloads:*** .NET desktop development, Desktop development with C++, Universal Windows Platform development, Game Development with Unity.

[image: Visual Studio Workloads Image]

***Templates I Can See:***

[image: Templates I can see when I search for "winfors"]

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0/

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to install .NET desktop development package in VS19.

Steps

1. Press create new project
2. Search for *.NET desktop development* (seen in picture A)
3. If it is not visible press the *Install more tools and features* link under *Not finding what you're looking for* (see picture B).
4. Search for the package and select it
5. Press the **Modify** button in the Visual Studio Installer

[image: Pic A]

[image: Pic B]

Comment: I have already installed .NET desktop development workload ( as I said in question ). But after uninstalling and reinstalling the same workload, I was able to find it. Thanks for your effort.